# Does the data packet header contain the destination device's private IP address or router's public IP address?

Tags: networking, router, ip

If data packet headers contain the `device's private IP address` (and **not** the `router's public IP address`), how will the device receive the data if only the **router** knows about the `device's private IP address`?

Comment: Assuming you're asking about communications over Internet, not over internal networks?

Comment: @user1686 yes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming IPV4

If the target device is not on the same LAN (as determined using the netmask), The packet emitted by the sender will have a destination IP-address of the external IP-address of target but a destination MAC address (e.g. Ethernet address) for the internal network interface of the router.

The MAC address of the local router's internal interface is typically obtained by an ARP request specifying the router's internal IP-address which is known from DHCP, static configuration, ICMP redirect, routing protocol message or other means.

If the source is behind a router that uses Network Address Translation (NAT), when the source's local router forwards the packet it rewrites the source's IP-address in the packet, replacing a local LAN IP-address with an external public IP-address of the router.

If the target is also behind NAT, the target router will typically have some sort of port-forwarding rule that forwards a TCP or UDP packet with a specific destination port number to a configured internal device using the internal IP-address of that device. For TCP connections, the router will remember the connection based on the usual four pieces of information including the sender's randomly chosen port number. This allows it to return packets in reply.

Typically both source and destination devices are each behind their local NAT router and see one of the other end's router's public IP-addresses as the destination address of the target. Typically nether end device knows or needs to know what IP-address the other end device uses on its private network (usually an address in one of the IPV4 address ranges reserved for internal use)

IPV6 works differently.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is [Network Address Translation (NAT)](https://www.comptia.org/content/guides/what-is-network-address-translation).

To the outside world, your devices are seen as the IP of the router, given by the ISP. *Inside the local area network (LAN)*, each device has an IP address supplied by the router. [Many manufacturers assign 192.168.1.*n*](https://www.techspot.com/guides/287-default-router-ip-addresses/) to the router and to connected devices *inside the LAN*, where *n* differs for each device. (It is also possible to assign an arbitrary fixed IP inside the LAN.) If those local IP addresses were visible to the whole internet, *everyone* would be chatting on a [giant (multi)party line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party_line_(telephony)) at 192.168.1.*n*.

The [local router is responsible for redirecting messages](https://www.quora.com/How-does-sender-IP-device-decide-to-deliver-a-packet-to-the-one-out-of-many-receivers-which-have-same-IP-addresses) to the local devices.

> "It... maintains a translation table between the public IP and source port, and the private IP and source port. This is the basis of Network Address Translation (NAT)."